# Can a CW complex have a subset of cells that is itself a CW complex, yet is not a subcomplex of the larger complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $(X, \mathcal{E})$ be a CW complex and
$\mathcal{E'} \subseteq \mathcal{E}$ be a subset of cells such that
$\mathcal{E'}$ is a CW decomposition of the space $X' = \bigcup_{e \in \mathcal{E'}} e \subseteq X$. Is $\mathcal{E'}$ then necessarily a subcomplex of $\mathcal{E}$?

I know that if $\mathcal{E'}$ is finite, then $X'$ is compact and thus closed in $X$, so that $\mathcal{E'}$ is a subcomplex of $\mathcal{E}$. But can we say anything in the infinite case? Intuition tells me there should be a counterexample, but I'm not able to come up with one.

Comment: Do you consider open or closed cells?

Comment: The cells are open.